# Tenured Gen memory always increasing in Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

My  **Java version is 8**.

I am testing a simple **ThreadPoolExecutor**  use case :-

- Executing new thread using ThreadPoolExecutor
- Printing done message in  new thread

Jconsole shows 'Tenured Gen memory' always increasing and it looks like Garbase collector is not cleaning memory.

**Why  Grabage collector is not realising Tenured Gen memory?**

Is this **memory leak**,  then what I am doing wrong ?

**Jconsole Tenured Gen screenshot**

[image: **Jconsole Tenured Gen screenshot**]

**App.java**

```
    public static int n = 0;
    private static int coreThreads = 40;
    private static int maxThreads = 200;
    private static int queueSize = 20;
    public static volatile boolean shuttingDown = false;
    final static BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize);
    final static  ThreadPoolExecutor reqExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(coreThreads, maxThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);    

public static void main( String[] args ) 
            {


                    System.out.println("App started...");
                    while(true){
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
                        {
                            reqExecutor.execute(new MulThread_Test());
                            /*reqExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    System.out.println("##############");
                                }
                            });*/
                        }
                        System.out.println("100 reqExecutor done.");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                }   
             }
```

**MulThread_Test.java**

```
  public class MulThread implements Runnable
{

    public void run()
    {
        try {
            execute();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finshed..!");
    }



    public void execute() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("working..");

    }
}
```

Comment: It's most likely because your program does way to little work for the garbage collector to kick in.

Comment: What happens when you click on "Perform GC"? That should prove @marstran 's point.